# Can I view a list of applications currently running background jobs in iOS?

Tags: ios, multitasking

A growing number of applications for iOS, especially those adjusted for iOS 7, support background tasks (so they complete a download or sync or whatever also if not in front).

Is there any chance to print a list of applications that are running background tasks (or have been currently), for example like the one used for location based services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option I have found is in Settings -> General -> Background App Refresh that shows all apps that are currently capable and enabled to do the refreshing. Unfortunately there is no indication of which one was active recently.

Comment: Hadn't found that yet, but at least partly solves the problem. I will wait for some more time, if there is no answer with information on recent tasks I will set this as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use [iStat](http://bjango.com/apps/) on all my systems. That gives me background and foreground apps as well as their resource usage. HTH

Comment: iStat can show which _iOS_ background applications are currently active? Could you add an example screenshot to your answer? I know some other tools, but they're not able to list any additional information to PID and priority...

Comment: I probably shot off too quickly. I get resource information that I find very useful. I use iExplorer for app lists. There is also an IOS Activity Monitor, that maybe useful.. https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/system-activity-monitor/id306192663?mt=8

Comment: Seems they're all only giving lists of apps, but not which are currently active. I guess Apple is not offering an API allowing to do this... :(

Comment: I found this one too: http://www.theappsware.com plays to mixed reviews though..